# How to get the latest (distinct) records filtered by a non unique field in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I'll demonstrate by using an example. This is the model (the primary key is implicit):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(null=False)
    description = models.CharField(null=True)
```

I have a list of skus, I need to get the latest descriptions for all skus in the filter list that are written in the table for the model Item. Latest item == greatest id.

I need a way to annotate the latest description per sku:

```
Item.objects.values("sku").filter(sku__in=list_of_skus).annotate(latest_descr=Latest('description').order_by("-id")
```

but this won't work for various reasons (excluding the missing aggregate function).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used postgres ArrayAgg aggregate function to aggregate the latest description like so:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

class ArrayAggLatest(ArrayAgg):
    template = "(%(function)s(%(expressions)s ORDER BY id DESC))[1]"

Item.objects.filter(sku__in=skus).values("sku").annotate(descr=ArrayAggLatest("description"))
```

The aggregate function aggregates all descriptions ordered by descending ID of the original table and gets the 1st element (0 element is None)

Comment: why you need aggregate? ask is simply: get the description from last row.

Comment: I don't need the last description i need the latest **descriptions** for **all skus** in the filter list.

Comment: how you can decide who is "latests" and whois not the latest?

Comment: latests are those descriptions on items with higher ids.

Answer (score -1):

```
Item.objects.values("sku").filter(sku__in=list_of_skus).annotate(latest_descr=Latest('description').lastest("-id")
```

Or use this

```
Item.objects.values("sku").filter(sku__in=list_of_skus).annotate(latest_descr=Latest('description').order_by("-id").reverse()[0]
```

Comment: values("sku") - what you mind here?

Answer (score -1):

Answer from @M.J.GH.PY or @dekomote war not correct.
If you have a model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(null=False)
    description = models.CharField(null=True)
```

this model has already by default `order_by= 'id',`

You don't need annotate something. You can:

## get the last object:

```
Item.objects.filter(sku__in=list_of_skus).last()
```

## get the last value of `description`:

```
Item.objects.filter(sku__in=list_of_skus).values_list('description', flat=True).last()
```

Both variants give you a `None` if a `queryset` is empty.

Comment: This will give me the last description of all descriptions belonging to the filtered skus. I need a map of sku: description where description is the most recent one for all skus in filter list.

Comment: in question i see:  I need to get the latest descriptions that are written in the table for the model Item. please update the question

Comment: I did. Note it said latest **descriptions**, not description.

Comment: Ok. how to define which descriptions are latest? Especially if id is random?

Comment: ID is not random. It's an integer field (django default)

Comment: Ok. how to define which descriptions are latest? i have in table ids 3, 4, 5. Probably 5 is the last. in query 3,4 - 4 is the last.  What you mean  description "latest". Which ids is latest in case ids 3,4,5,6?